# Assign object from google scripts to local variable using AJAX

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, cross-origin-read-blocking

I wrote a custom Google Script which outputs an object for me and I would like to be able to call it and assign it to a variable which is then used to display data on a website.

**HTML Header:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>JQVMap - World Map</title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <link href="../dist/jqvmap.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/jquery.vmap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.vmap.sampledata.deaths.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.vmap.sampledata.infected.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
                map: 'world_en',
                backgroundColor: '#333333',
                color: '#ffffff',
                hoverOpacity: 0.8,
                selectedColor: '#3498DB',
                enableZoom: true,
                showTooltip: true,
                scaleColors: ['#F3A291', '#FF4F3B'],
                values: infected_data,
                normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
                onLabelShow: function (event, label, code) {
                    label.html('<div class="map-tooltip"><h1 class="header"> ' + label.html() + '</h1><p class="description">Infected: ' + infected_data[code] + '</p><p class="description">Deaths: ' + death_data[code] + '</p></div>');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

**Google Scripts File:**

```
function doGet() {
    var result = {};
    var infected = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data').getDataRange().getValues();
    var death = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data').getDataRange().getValues();
    result = makeObject(infected);

    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}

function makeObject(multiArr) {
    var obj = {};
    var countrystats = {};
    var headers = multiArr.shift();

    for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        countrystats[i] = multiArr.map(function (app) {
            return app[i];
        })
    }

    for (var m = 0; m < countrystats[1].length; m++) {
        obj[countrystats[1][m]] = 0;
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < countrystats[1].length; j++) {
        var TempVar;
        TempVar = obj[countrystats[1][j]];
        obj[countrystats[1][j]] = TempVar + countrystats[3][j];

    }

    return obj;
}
```

Google Scripts Output (using the JSON View chrome extension):

```
{
cn: 8134,
th: 23,
mo: 7,
us: 5,
jp: 11,
kr: 4,
sg: 10,
vn: 2,
fr: 5,
np: 1,
my: 8,
ca: 3,
ci: 1,
lk: 1,
au: 9,
de: 4,
fn: 1
}
```

This is a public link with the object/data i want on it (the same object shown above):web app:  https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzsyQNJwDvQc5SvNGEDZZOoNI3XxNar9PA9sRucZx7mgzfWpFQ/exec

So basically anyone who uses it should be able to access it. I just need a way to assign that data to a local JS variable. The google sheets script is published as a web app. If I'm not mistaken there is a setting to allow anyone, even anonymous to access it.

**Here is my attempt at an AJAX request:**

```
 var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzsyQNJwDvQc5SvNGEDZZOoNI3XxNar9PA9sRucZx7mgzfWpFQ/exec";


      var infected_data = jQuery.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        //dataType: "jsonp"
      });
```

If I uncomment the jsonp I get an error:

> jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=JXkCjiJjhcjndRREjoGyVNkZNkD-HvKpEPkpicQBm9nR9OkxjGXdYuOPsLxbJf-B9Rgifl5NWMtzgjfVGuMdGxTJrjKnRpdcOJmA1Yb3SEsKFZqtv3DaNYcMrmhZHmUMWojr9NvTBuBLhyHCd5hHazTNYZyoqG0ZuVXpWSNdoeLErB4AfUCNPKJHgELe5WaAmN5SlwIhonlWkkbFzR8kUwjKrMtdq9u-YqreD7W_KJ_aVqKVBTehAuogPCoZCfVc4yJf5ieDCdMDbXQ8FZZq8iSedsk1Px1LnPBLM8W-ZRcknnbJNT8dS525XG1pNEBR&lib=Mw_Scq3iKhByBS86NJpd_CngcdEShCw7K with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

I don't get any errors if i remove it. However, i still can't see the data on my interactive map (My application).

**Using Fetch:**

[image]
[image]
const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzsyQNJwDvQc5SvNGEDZZOoNI3XxNar9PA9sRucZx7mgzfWpFQ/exec";

```
  // Declare an async function
  const getData = async () => {
  // Use the await keyword to let JS know this variable has some latency so it should wait for it to be filled 
  // When the variable is fetched, use the .then() callback to carry on 
    const DataJSON = await fetch(url).then(response => 
      response.json()
    ).then(parsedResponse => parsedResponse)
  
    return await DataJSON
  };
  
  console.log(getData());
  var infected_data = getData();
```

**Converting Integers in object to Strings**
The object needs to be in a format like this:

```
var infected_data = {
  cn: "83",
  th: "0",
  mo: "0",
  au: "0",
  sg: "0",
  tw: "0",
  us: "0",
  jp: "0",
  my: "0",
  kr: "0",
  fx: "0",
  vn: "0",
  kh: "0",
  ca: "0",
  ci: "0",
  np: "0",
  lk: "0",
  
};
```

Comment: [Sending jsonp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#serving_jsonp_in_web_pages) is the easiest way.

Comment: Something like this? :         <script src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzsyQNJwDvQc5SvNGEDZZOoNI3XxNar9PA9sRucZx7mgzfWpFQ/exec?prefix=SetInfected"></script>
        <script>
            function SetInfected(data){
                var infected_data = data;
            }
        
        </script>         With this i get the CORB problem again.

Comment: Yes. Your `doGet()` should also be modified accordingly. Stringify the json with prefix and set mime as JavaScript(Don't forget to publish a new version and deploy).

Comment: Perfect, I got it to work with your method and Max Steenbergen's below. If you take a look above (updated post) i believe the last step i need is to convert the integer values to strings. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't think there's any shortcut. Loop through and convert to string. Follow up questions are better asked as new questions.

Comment: I actually found a really cool method I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the Question to Convert Integers to Strings:
Try something like this:

```
function toString(o) {
  Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
    if (typeof o[k] === 'object') {
      return toString(o[k]);
    }

    o[k] = '' + o[k];
  });

  return o;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're likely having issues with the call being asynchronous, which would mean you're reading the data before it is actually returned from Google's servers. Try using `promises` and the `fetch` API

```js
const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzsyQNJwDvQc5SvNGEDZZOoNI3XxNar9PA9sRucZx7mgzfWpFQ/exec";

// Declare an async function
const getData = async () => {
// Use the await keyword to let JS know this variable has some latency so it should wait for it to be filled 
// When the variable is fetched, use the .then() callback to carry on 
  const DataJSON = await fetch(url).then(response => 
    response.json()
  ).then(parsedResponse => parsedResponse)

  return await DataJSON
};

console.log(await getData())
```

Comment: Take a look at the updated post, this is what i get in the console. Still doesn't seem to give the data, or maybe it is just in some other weird format.

Comment: Oops, ok I see the object with all its data!!! Sweet! this seems to be working well. Now the only problem i think is that it is not being assigned correctly to Var Infected_Data. EDIT: I forgot, the values need to be strings, not numbers. Is there a quick and easy way to convert them.

Comment: And how can i access just the object inside the promise?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is not sensitive,  You could use jsonp to bypass cors:

#### Server side:

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput("infect(" +JSON.stringify(result)+ ")").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
```

#### Client side:

```
<script>function infect(data){ infectedData =  data }</script>
<script src="URL_OF_YOUR_SCRIPT"></script>
```

#### References:

- [Jsonp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#serving_jsonp_in_web_pages)
- [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)